# how to see all revisions related to a particular string in a file with mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to generate a list of changesets that affected a particular line of a file?  Annotate will let me see the last changeset to affect a particular line, I would like to chain annotations for a particular line back until it was first added.

Comment: I have not seen any way other than traverse annotations and build your own solution for this purpose.

Comment: In case of pure hg ann you will not be able to find previous changeset, affected line, from output - see my example for revision 2 case

Comment: Turns out rather than caring about a particular line, watching a particular symbol was effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended (and slightly alternated) version of pyfunc comment, without "ready-to-use" solution, only draft, with samples from my repo

- Define **all** changesets, which affect file (I'm lazy to write final gawk-code)

> hg log --template "{rev}\n" functions.php
>
> 3
>   2
>   1
>   0

For each revision from set:

> hg ann -r $REV functions.php  | grep "load_theme_" >> string.txt

string.txt will be after all `hg ann |` (none for rev 0 was grepped)

```
2: load_theme_textdomain('fiver', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
2: load_theme_textdomain('fiver', get_template_directory() . '/languages');
1: load_theme_textdomain('fiver', get_template_directory() . '/translation');
```

- Remove duplicates with `uniq` pipe and get final result

Frank says: thanks, that got me started, I ended up using the following from Powershell to watch what changesets affected a particular symbol:

```
$history = hg log --template "{rev}\n" $filename
$history | % { $_; hg log -vpr $_ $filename | select-string $symbolBeingWatched }
```

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
hg grep --all symbolBeingWatched
```

or if you really just want the list of revisions

```
hg grep --all symbolBeingwatched | cut -d : -f 2 | sort -u -n
```

Comment: real nice.  I hate being fickle though, moral dilemma if I reassign the answer.

Comment: I don't care about the points (in fact if my answer gets 10 up votes more than the picked answer I think I get a bonus), but the goal of the site is to help future searchers find the best answer quickly, not necessarily to answer your specific instance of the question.  NBD, though.